# Django filter objects id and search for the full name in User model

Tags: django

I have a problem of solving this for the whole day and can't get it right. Please someone help me...

> book_obj =
> Book.objects.filter(status_sold=True).order_by('-date_sold')

result will be something like this:
id = 2
title = 'bla bla bla bla...'
author = 3 ***---> id from the User model (not a foreign key)***
status_sold = True
date_sold = '2021-05-10'

I want to view that data in the template, but the author I want to display the name instead of number 3 as an id of the author. How to solve this ?

> author_name = User.objects.get(id= ???????? )

so I can use ***{{ author_name.get_full_name }}*** later in the template

Thx in advanced....

Answer (score 0):

Use this in a template. The author user object is already attached to the book object so you don’t need to fetch it from the database again.

`{{ book_obj.author.get_full_name }}`

Another option is to set the`__str__` method on the user object to

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_full_name
```

Then in the template you can just do

`{{ book_obj.author }}`

Comment: somehow the author field is not a Foreign key to User

Comment: Ok can you include the relevant code in question?

Answer (score 0):

If you show a bit more of your models, it may be easier to provide a more concrete answer, but I think we've got enough to give some help.

In your template, where you have author like :

```
{{author}}
```

you can simply add on the property you want with dot notation:

```
{{author.full_name}}
```

or what ever you put for the field containing the full name.

No need to separately pass a user object in your context. This way works well in loops as well.

Link to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#variables

**EDIT: apologies - missed the no foreign key bit.**

you may be looking at custom template tags.

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_author_name(key):
    author = Author.objects.get(pk=key)
    return author.full_name
```

then use it in template like:
`{{ author|get_author_name }}`

You could probably jazz it up a bit and add an attribute as an arg. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters